# Problem with Showing Query Results on a Form

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm having a Projects lists Continuous form where the form's Record Source is based upon a table.

I have a requirement to display a field from another table which is linked back to original table using its primary key. The primary key is a AutoNumber field, but when displaying in the form I've used Input mask something like this `"TMG/FEA/"0000.`

So I made:

- a unbound list box
- and made the Row source as the query which displays the relevant information from second table

This query was created using primary key displayed in form (I mean the `[Forms]![Form Name].[Field]` ) as the where clause.

But the results returns blank. I'm Stuck here. I'm not sure if the query is not working due to the Input Mask or because of something else. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably, make the RecordSource a SQL that joins the two tables

Comment: @donPablo If i have to change the RecordSource of the entire form to a query, will the form be able to write the new records data back to first table? I don't have a clue. Moreover this one field is just for glancing, no updating to table of any sort. That's why I kept as unbound field and just query the required info and display it in the unbound field

Comment: Can include the other table if does not result in non-editable dataset. If this other table is a lookup table then should be okay. Alternative is DLookup().

Comment: It is too unclear what are you supposed to do to my mind. Keep smaller sentences, more your goals, about desired behaviour of controls. Split it to parts

Comment: 'which is linked back to original table' - what do you mean by this clause?

Comment: @VanNg I mean the first table primary key is used as foreign key in the second table to link the records. I don't know how else to express this relationship. This relationship between the tables is what I meant as linked back to original table.

Comment: Is there one and only one record in second table for record in first table?

Comment: @VanNg My goal is to display one single field of information from another table along with all of the contents of first table in a Continuous form. This Continuous form uses the first table as it Record Source. Both the tables are linked by primary key foreign key relationship as said in above comment. So I made a query that returns this piece of information and made it to display in a unbound list box in the same form.

Comment: And it is better to provie table structure, sample data and query text - there must be some error in query building, I think

Comment: @VanNg yes only one record in second table for each of record in the first table

Comment: This is the SQL query that was generated by Access itself when I made the query with Query Design `SELECT [TYRE SIZE] & " - " & [PATTERN_NAME] AS [Tyre Name]
FROM [TYRE SIZES] INNER JOIN ([PROJECT DETAILS] INNER JOIN ([PATTERN TABLE] INNER JOIN [TYRE TABLE] ON [PATTERN TABLE].ID = [TYRE TABLE].PATTERNID_FK) ON [PROJECT DETAILS].ID = [TYRE TABLE].PROJECTID_FK) ON [TYRE SIZES].ID = [TYRE TABLE].TYRESIZEID_FK
WHERE ((([PROJECT DETAILS].ID)=[Forms]![FEA - PROJECTS LIST]![ID]));
` Can you help how to share the table structure? I made it using the GUI

Comment: This is too complex query for such simple goal. I'd write example in answer part

Comment: @VanNg you can consider this as simplified query instead of the above one. `SELECT [PROJECT DETAILS].ID, [TYRE SIZES].[TYRE SIZE]
FROM [TYRE SIZES] INNER JOIN ([PROJECT DETAILS] INNER JOIN [TYRE TABLE] ON [PROJECT DETAILS].ID = [TYRE TABLE].PROJECTID_FK) ON [TYRE SIZES].ID = [TYRE TABLE].TYRESIZEID_FK
WHERE ((([PROJECT DETAILS].ID)=[Forms]![FEA - PROJECTS LIST]![ID]));
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add to form field listbox, and set following values:

- `Data`: primary key of your first table

After this, that field will duplicate ID value. Now you should transform RecordSource of this field in order to see contents from second table. So you should set:

- `SELECT [PrimaryForeignKeyID], [DetailedField] FROM tblSecond;`. Actually I don't know the contents of your second table. Whereas `PrimaryForeignKeyID` is a field that links second table to first, so-called `FK`.
- After this set following properties of list box:
- - `ColumnCount = 2`
- - `ColumnWidth = 0;2`
- - `AllowEdits = False`
- Save form and open it for viewing.

In this case, your listbox will show the associated contents of second table on form.

So to my mind it is better for you to do such simple tables and forms, and you'll realize idea.

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, this is the kind result I'm looking for. Correct me if I'm wrong, the SQL query should be like `SELECT [PrimaryID], [DetailedData1] from tblSecond WHERE [PrimaryID]=[Forms]![FrmMain]![Primary ID]`. The column width part I have done it already. I'll share my table structure and query I have used in some time.

Comment: No, where condition is not needed in this case.`SELECT [PrimaryID], [DetailedData1] from tblSecond` only. You should assign `ID` value from first table to  data parameter of this field. In this case, listbox searches for associated value in record source query, where first parameter `PrimaryID` is equal to current value of cell. For each record result will be corresponding.

Comment: Hard to explain, but when you'll notice, it would be very easy. So just try propagated solution

Comment: Sure sir, I'll try it to out and let you know how it went.

Comment: http://wdfiles.ru/e9dV - uploaded file with described structure, that should give you capability to test how it works. There is no even VBA code, just field references

Comment: I gave your method a try. This was the query structure similar to your method: https://ibb.co/RNPK0jN . The query returns the answer of the first record for all the records. Maybe I didnt understand the data parameter properly. Can you elaborate on that sir?

Comment: I kept the bound column parameter as 2and kept the width of the second column as 0. Is it still required to change the first field to ID?

Comment: Ok I made a small change where instead of taking Foreign key of Second table, I used the primary key of the first table itself (like this https://ibb.co/FBqzKCf ) and gave the primary key of the record as Control Source, it matches properly. I disabled the field so none of them tamper with primary key of the table. Thank you sir.

Comment: And you can always mark answer as that allows to solve your problem, to help others!